# Modify behaviour of a R6 class' initialize method depending on input type

Tags: r, oop, r6

My goal is to modify the behavior of the initialize method depending on the type of the argument. For example, if I call `MyClass$new(list())` I'd like to initialize my object with a list, and if I call `MyClass$new("foo")` I'd like to initialize the object with a character string. I think S3 generics are very useful for that, so I did something like this:

```
initialize_test_class <- function(x) UseMethod("initialize_test_class")

initialize_test_class.default <- function(x) {
  warning("don't know what to do")
}

initialize_test_class.list <- function(x) {
  print("initialized with a list")
}

initialize_test_class.character <- function(x) {
  print("initialized with a character")
}

TestClass <- R6::R6Class(
  classname = "TestClass",
  public = list(
    initialize = function(x) {
      initialize_test_class(x) 
    }
  )
)


TestClass$new(list(a = 1))
TestClass$new("foo")
```

And it works, but I'm wondering maybe there's a more elegant way to do it? Some more general advices about OOP good practices in such cases are welcome, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If initialization of the R6 class is the sole purpose of your S3 class, I would say you are definitely over-engineering this. There are other methods for type-checking input that are simpler (and possibly safer) than relying on S3 dispatch. For example `is.list(x)` and `is.character(x)` might be useful here, or `inherits(x, 'list')` and `inherits(x, 'character')`.

So I think a more elegant solution here would be:

```r
TestClass <- R6::R6Class(
  classname = "TestClass",
  public = list(
    initialize = function(x) {
      if(is.list(x)) cat('initialized with a list\n') else 
      if(is.character(x)) cat('initialized with a character\n') else 
      cat("I don't know what to do\n")
    }
  )
)
```

Though depending on the complexity of your initialization methods, you *may* wish to bring the methods outside of the class definition, but don't have them as S3:

```r
init_list <- function(x) cat('initialized with a list\n')
init_char <- function(x) cat('initialized with a character\n')
init_none <- function(x) cat("I don't know what to do\n")

TestClass <- R6::R6Class(
  classname = "TestClass",
  public = list(
    initialize = function(x) {
      if(is.list(x)) init_list(x) else 
      if(is.character(x)) init_char(x) else init_none(x)
    }
  )
)
```

Both of which give the same result:

```r
TestClass$new(list(a = 1))
#> initialized with a list
#> <TestClass>
#>   Public:
#>     clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
#>     initialize: function (x)

TestClass$new("foo")
#> initialized with a character
#> <TestClass>
#>   Public:
#>     clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
#>     initialize: function (x)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. The downside of this solution I see is that anytime I'd like to instantiate my class from a new type, e.g. numeric, I'd need to modify the class' code: extend the list of if...else statements and add another handler inside my class definition. With generic method I could avoid this. So I think in very simple cases Your answer is OK. I'm thinking more about overriding (is it good word?) the initialize method

Comment: I understand what you mean, @JakubMałecki, and I think if you were writing OO code for a strongly-typed compiled language you would be right. However, most R code works on a handful of basic types and it is normally feasible to handle all of these at the time of class definition. There's nothing _wrong_ with your S3 dispatch method, and it _might_ be the best solution if you are _really_ going to have an R6 class with a very broad remit. However, the design principle of YAGNI ('you ain't gonna need it') is one I find often applies in OO design, especially in a weakly typed interpreted language